# Code says 'use of undeclared identifier", but is is in the code

Tags: c, cs50

The code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    // TODO: Print the winner

    if (score1 > score2)
    {
        printf("\nThe winner is player 1!");
    }

    else if (score2 > score1)
    {
        printf("\nThe winner is player 2!");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("\nThat's a tie!");
    }

    int compute_score(string word);
    int total_points = 0;
    {
        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word); i < n; i++)
        {
            if (isupper(word[i]))
            {
                total_points = total_points + POINTS[word[i] - 'A'];
            }
            else if (islower(word[i]))
            {
                total_points = total_points + POINTS[word[i] - 'a'];
            }

            return total_points;
        }
    }
}
```

'word' is the cause of this error. Apparently, it is undeclared. However, it is written in the code. Why is this the case? This happens often to me and I mostly figure it out by changing some random things, but I'd like to know the exact reason so I can avoid it next time.

Comment: `int compute_score(string word);` -> `int compute_score(string word)`. That is, remove `;`. Also need to properly enclose the code after that with `{ }`.

Comment: thanks, that worked! however, it is giving me this error next: function definition is not allowed here (where I add the curly brackets after int compute_score(string word)

Comment: `int compute_score(string word);` is a function declaration, it's inside `main`, moreover it's alredy declared before, I assume you want that to be the function definition, in any case it shouldn't be inside `main`.

Comment: Please review your C book. Correctly defining a function is basic C syntax and Stack Overflow is not a substitute for reading the text book or tutorial.

Comment: I keep up with all my course work and have received zero help from TA's or professors at my uni and as a complete beginner, I'm having a hard time trying to understand everything without help within a short period of time. So instead of trying to review something for hours trying to see where I went wrong, I figured i'd ask nicely here, because sometimes it's a simple answer.

Comment: @anastaciu, ah that seems to be what I missed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
    else
    {
        printf("\nThat's a tie!");
    }

    int compute_score(string word);
    int total_points = 0;
    {
```

this is not valid C code!  Suggest:

```
    else
    {
        printf("\nThat's a tie!");
    }
}  // end of main()


int compute_score(string word)
{
    int total_points = 0;
```

Comment: Your first snippet is valid C code, although doesn't do what the OP intended